# How do you build from a specific TFS 2008 Changeset in Jenkins?

Tags: version-control, jenkins, build-automation

I am attempting to create a manual build in Jenkins that will build a specific changeset of code from TFS for a deployment into a testing / production environment.

Currently I am only able to use TFS in Jenkins to pull everything up to the newest Changeset out of TFS.

I am running Jenkins version 1.471 with the TFS plugin version 1.20

Has anyone run into the problem, and do you know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is missing, but seems to be under way according to the comments of this Jira issue:

[TFS Support to get labels](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3002)

So, not specific changesets, but for me labels would be good enough as they can be applied at any time.