# Deciding which changesets go in Jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins, tfs, version-control, commit, changeset

I am trying to create a build in Jenkins, from certain changesets made in TFS. 
I want to be able to decide which changesets should go in the build and which should be excluded. 
I saw an earlier question [How do you build from a specific TFS 2008 Changeset in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200517/how-do-you-build-from-a-specific-tfs-2008-changeset-in-jenkins) which provided the answer using labels. Haven't tried it yet. But the question is 3 yrs old and I wanted to know if anyone has found an answer.

Any help would be appreciated. If it is not possible in Jenkins, please suggest any other tool that provides such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian Bamboo  with TFS Repository Plugin
provides a solution for you :)
https://bitbucket.org/stellaritysoftware/tfs-repository-plugin/wiki/Home#!34-build-from-a-label-or-a-revision

BTW I've been looking around the [tfs-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin) and although the docs doesn't mention "specific checkout by changeSet" I think there is a good chance that setting the VERSION_SPEC variable to change-set value, might do the trick for you.